# Is better POW() or POWER()?

Tags: mysql, sql, pow

I must make an exponentiation of a number and I don't know which function to use between `POW()` and `POWER()`. Which of the two functions is better?

Looking at the MySQL documentation I saw that they are synonymous, but I wanted to understand if there was a reason for two functions that do the same thing.

Comment: I have not checked, but I assume the reason there are two functions is for compatibility with other RDBMS brands.

Comment: At some point the reason to have two functions that are synonyms is down to arbitrary decisions with no clear advantage or disadvantage. There's two functions because there's two functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`POWER` is the synonym of `POW`. So nothing is better, it is the same:

> `POWER(X,Y)`
>   This is a synonym for `POW()`.

Using two different names for the same function gives you the possibility to port an SQL query from one dialect to an other dialect without (big) changes.

---

**An example:**

You want to use the following TSQL query on MySQL too:

```
SELECT POWER(2,2) -- 4
```

Now you can write these query specific for the dialects:

```
SELECT POWER(2,2) -- 4 - TSQL (POW is not available on TSQL)
SELECT POW(2,2)   -- 4 - MySQL
```

But you can also use the `POWER` function on MySQL since this is a synonym for `POW`:

```
SELECT POWER(2,2) -- 4 - TSQL and MySQL
```

Comment: Aliases for function names are common in many languages. Some people might be used to `POWER`, others `POW`, like JavaScript's [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow). It's like how `!=` and `<>` are equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

`pow` and `power` are synonyms in MySQL.

I'd use `power` since it's part of the ANSI SQL standard and using it would make your code easier to port if you ever decide to use a different database.